# Ionic 2: error while running on Android platform

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 when I used the command `ionic cordova run android` I had this error:

```
Fetching plugin "mx.ferreyra.callnumber@~0.0.2" via npm
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not found. 
Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, 
set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. 
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project.
```

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have Android Studio installed. If it is, then set the environment variable mentioned in the error to the directory of where your SDK is,
on Windows `%AppData%/Local/Android/SDK`

Comment: I have android studio installed, and I set environment variable in .bashrc file (I'm using Ubuntu) but I still have the same problem